# PHP ImageWorkshop package with Composer failing

Tags: namespaces, php-5.3, composer-php, global-namespace

So very strange issue. I only recently starting using auto loading in PHP 5.3+ and of course, this inevitably led to composer.

I did a really simple install with composer with only one package, php Image Workshop.

In addition to my own auto loader, I fire of the vendor/autoload.php

Then in my code:

```
use PHPImageWorkshop\ImageWorkshop;
$imagelayer = ImageWorkshop::initFromPath( $filename );
```

The namespace is valid and I get into the class which immediately throws an error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function PHPImageWorkshop\\imageCreateFromJPEG() in /var/www/html/vendor/sybio/image-workshop/src/PHPImageWorkshop/ImageWorkshop.php on line 55
```

imageCreateFromJPEG should be in the global namespace already, but the code in the class doesn't prefix it with a '\'.

Is this all right? I feel like I'm looking for a black cat in a dark room.

Comment: So this ended up being a total rookie mistake. I'm working on a server that I didn't configure (only a reason, not an excuse) and it didn't occur to me that GD wasn't installed.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is GD is not available in your PHP instalation. Try to install php5-gd and it should work.

Good luck